# Sorting merged XML elements by name using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

My merged file looks like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lineup>
   <artists>
      <artist id="124">
         <name>Pascal &amp; Pearce</name>
         <genres>
            <genre>dance</genre>
            <genre>club</genre>
         </genres>
         <writeup>
      After a chance meeting in 2007, Pascal Ellinas and Dave Pearce began the long winding road that is now the stellar production and DJ duo of Pascal &amp; Pearce.
    </writeup>
         <gig>
            <day>SUNDAY</day>
            <time>
               <starts>17:00</starts>
               <ends>19:00</ends>
            </time>
         </gig>
         <photo format="jpg">pascal-pierce</photo>
      </artist>
      <aritst id="101">
         <name>Dan Patlansky</name>
         <genres>
            <genre>Blues</genre>
            <genre>Rock</genre>
            <genre>Jazz</genre>
         </genres>
         <writeup>
      What Dan Patlansky can do with a six-string Fender Stratocaster at the age of 26, most critically acclaimed guitarists will never quite achieve in a lifetime.
    </writeup>
         <gig>
            <day>Friday</day>
            <time>
               <starts>13:00</starts>
               <ends>15:00</ends>
            </time>
         </gig>
         <photo format="jpg">dan-patlansky</photo>
      </aritst>
      etc
```

I need to sort the artist names alphabetically, this is what i have so far but it doesn't produce anything. This is my XSL file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" media-type="text/xml" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <lineup>
        <artists>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="artists/artist">
                <xsl:sort select="name" order="ascending" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </artists>
        </lineup>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My output produces an empty file with just a  tag. My merged file is my source file.
Help would be much appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick fix, change `<xsl:apply-templates select="artists/artist">` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="lineup/artists/artist">`.

It would be simpler to match on

```
<xsl:template match="artists">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="artist">
      <xsl:sort select="name"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just tried that it only shows the first "artist" alone. The "Pascal &amp; Pearce" details only.

Comment: because your second artist is a `aritst`

Comment: @wero how do I fix that?

Comment: @KhanyisileC correct the xml file or learn about xpath unions

Comment: Thank you so much @wero. Found it :)